# How can I push link to an JS array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have three links that express three different images. I want to push these links to an array and I can show off my images on the screen. How can I do that

This is my JS code, is that correct ??
Thanks a lot.

```js
let cardsource = [
    "<a href = 'https://bom.to/Qd87vw'> Card 1</a>",
    "<a href = 'https://bom.to/P21flg'>Card 2 </a>",
    "<a href = 'https://bom.to/dFwwNw'>Card 3 </a>",
];
for (var index = 0; index < cardsource.lengh; index++) {
    console.log(cardsource[index]);
}
```

Comment: Normally one would only store URL in the array and generate HTML from them when needed. But what you have here would do too.

Comment: I would look into [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use insertAdjacentHTML function.
[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

```
let cardsource = [
    "<a href = 'https://bom.to/Qd87vw'> Card 1</a>",
    "<a href = 'https://bom.to/P21flg'>Card 2 </a>",
    "<a href = 'https://bom.to/dFwwNw'>Card 3 </a>",
];
cardsource.map(val => document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', val));
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't push tag inside array, just push the link which directly gives you the image.

```
let cardsource = ['https://bom.to/Qd87vw', 'https://bom.to/P21flg', 'https://bom.to/dFwwNw'];

cardsource.map((item) => <img src={item}>)
```

This is just to give you the logical view on what you must do instead what you have done. If you are working with .jsx this code would work.

Comment: If you give a code example, please make sure it's valid. Your example is not valid Javascript.

Comment: yes, edited my answer accordingly. Thank you

Comment: There is no `jsx` in the op tags, it's like giving an example of python when question is about javascript...

Comment: ok, what do you want me to do?